# the architecture of an enterprise application should be a single page application all the time?

Tags: architecture, client, single-page-application

For Instance, we are going to develop an enterprise application that supports financial, management, human resource and logistic needs of all companies with different structure and policies.

I want to know whether it is better to choose single page application for client architecture or using another architecture?

Requirements: The subsystems work without any problems. The data will be synchronized together, total user=3,000,000, performance is important- constraints: team with 30 members involve 8 senior developer, 13 junior developer, 4 analyst, 3 tester, 2 R&D.

We have 7 sub-systems that are belong to Ministry of Education such as:

1- Organization  units management 2- Accountant 3- Salary system 4- student management system 5-personnel system 6- User Management 7- time attendance

I explain based on priority:

Student management system
- total schools: 381,424
- total students: about 3,500,000
- business : registering, reports, courses, scores, teachers

Time attendance
- total staff: about 1,000,000
- business: time tracking & attendance, mission, leave, define different shifts,..

Salary
-    business: Salary statement, Generate salary slip, Bonus details, Salary cash statement, Allowance/Deduction, Tax calculation

Personnel system
- total staff: about 1,000,000
-   business: long profile include : insurance, history of education, military, marriage, bank account, sports, art and other important activities

Organization  units management
- total units: about 3000
- business: units, positions, approval requests, unit grading, organization charts

User Management
business: authentication, authorization, users, roles, permission, groups

In addition system requires workflow
also project funding is not clear in step yet

if description isn't clear please add comment.

Comment: Can you give more specific details about the requirements and constraints?

Comment: requirements: The subsystems work without any problems,The data will be synchronized together, total user=3,000,000, performance is important-
constraints: team with 30 members involve 8 senior developer, 13 junior developer, 4 analyst, 3 tester, 2 R&D

Comment: This question is impossible to answer with the amount of information given.  There is NEVER one-size-fits-all answers for architecture, we would need information about business,system,user,quality,scalability,funding,etc..

Comment: @RobConklin I'm sorry to reply late

Answer (score 1):

Ok, you are asking stack-overflow to design a very large-scale system.  I like this site, and many questions can be answered, but this is not the forum for this kind of question.  You need a professional engagement from some senior software architects.

That being said, if you are really looking to stack-overflow to design your system, then you should most definitely not take this project on.  You will do many times better taking an existing open-source school information system and customizing it to your particular needs.  Involve yourself in one of these existing projects, and contribute back to it as needed.

Take a look at this site:
https://www.openeducat.org/blog/open-source-1/post/4-top-open-source-school-management-system-and-erp-30

Alternatively, use the same approach some of the other open-source systems do, and pick an ERP to extend to cover your needs.  Regardless, you will do much better starting from something that already works, and covers needs such as financial management, HR management, attendance management etc...

These have well-established solutions, and there is no value in reinventing these wheels.  Get some of those analysts to start doing functionality gaps, get some of your other staff going with POCs of the various solutions, and follow whatever architecture is already in-place for one of these systems.